# Finding a single element in a list using list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

The function `valueOf` gets the `Int` value of the corresponding `String` out of a tuple list.
Can someone explain how the third line works?

```
type State = [(String,Int)]

valueOf :: State -> String -> Int
valueOf xs var  = head [b | (a,b) <- xs , a ==var ]
```

I've never seen a Haskell expression like that, I'm more used to expression like this:

```
(\xs -> length xs > 15)
```

Comment: Note that this is not a good implementation. `head` is generally frowned upon; this is definitely not a safe use (the program will just crash if the key isn't found, with no easy way to see where things went awry). Better would be something like this: `valueOf :: State -> String -> Maybe Int`. For this safe signature, there are actually standard functions available which do the lookup just like you want: `lookup` or `find`. Also, consider [switching to `Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map-Lazy.html), which is more efficient for such lookups.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no lambda expression. What you are seeing is a list comprehension, which is a way of creating a list of values satisfying a certain condition.

In this case the comprehension `[b | (a,b) <- xs , a ==var ]` means something like: create a list of all `b`s such that `(a, b)` is an element of list `xs`, where `a` is equal to `var`.

In imperative pseudo-code you could write it as

```
result = EMPTY_LIST
for (a,b) in xs:
    if a == var:
        result.add(b)
return result
```

So, the whole `valueOf` function works by generating a list of values that have the right `String` key, and then uses `head` function to get the first one. Note that if there is no match, the whole computation will crash.

Answer (score 4):

`(a,b) <- xs` is not a lambda, it is a generator in a [list comprehension](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11)

In this case it successively binds the pairs in the source list `xs` and matches them with `(a, b)`. The boolean guard `a == var` retains all elements for which `a == var` is true.

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
valueOf xs var  = head [b | (a,b) <- xs , a ==var ]
```

is equivalent to the lambda expression

```
valueOf = \xs var -> head [b | (a,b) <- xs , a ==var ]
```

However, I guess that what really confuses you is the list comprehension `[b | (a,b) <- xs , a ==var ]`. This expression builds a list as follows: loop over all the pairs in `xs` (this is the part `(a,b)<-xs`), keep only those pairs where `a==var`, then take all the remaining `b` and build a list with those.

With `head` in front, this will simply look in `xs` for the first pair whose first component is `var`, and return its second component. If no such pair is found, a runtime error will be generated (unless `xs` is an infinite list, which will cause the program to run forever).